# What does "function() { get: function(...) { ... } }" in JavaScript mean?

Tags: javascript

I found the following code snippet [here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/10/more-angularjs-magic-to-supercharge-your-webapp.html#you-should-be-using-custom-services):

```
App.factory('myHttp',['$http',function($http) {
  return function() {
    get: function(url, success, fail) {
      $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      }).error(fail);
    }
  };
}]);
```

I wonder what does this syntax mean:

```
function() {
  get: function(...) { ... }
}
```

Comment: That almost looks invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's a typo. It's definitely a syntax error. It resembles the [ES5 getter notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get), but even so, you can only use that with a property name, like `get response() { ... }`.

Perhaps what the author intended was:

```
App.factory('myHttp',['$http',function($http) {
  return {
    get: function(url, success, fail) {
      $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      }).error(fail);
    }
  };
}]);
```

which is *not* the ES5 getter notation, but a simple object with one property called `get`, referring to [HTTP GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) (as opposed to POST).

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably sure a JavaScript parser would interpret `get` there as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). It's useless, because labels are only useful for loop control, and there is no loop here. Still, it's mostly legal syntax. That said, Firefox's interpreter will complain about a dead-code anonymous function.